# My update query is not working. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and am trying to update an access database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

Below is my code for the update query, everything appears to be working fine, but the database does not update.

```
public int ChangeProduct(string _ProductID, double _ProductPrice)
    {
        int a = 0;
        string queryString = "UPDATE product SET productPrice = @productPrice WHERE productID = @productId";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {

            OleDbCommand updateProduct = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", _ProductID);
            updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productPrice", _ProductPrice);
            connection.Open();
            a = updateProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of that?

Comment: 0, which has me baffled.

Comment: I see that parameterized names are being used in query string (which currently doesn't supported by Access), thereby try to change the query with this: `"UPDATE product SET productPrice = ? WHERE productID = ?"`.

Comment: It's working fine with my insert and select queries.

Comment: Are the columns productID and productPrice in your DB VARCHAR?

Comment: productID is, productPrice is set as currency, I've just tried changing the double from the code to a decimal, but that didn't do anything

Comment: Have you using OLE DB .NET Provider to connect with Access DB? If the positional query above still won't work, probably second `AddWithValue` should be changed to `updateProduct.Parameters.Add("@productPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = _ProductPrice;`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto any difference between the two ways?

Comment: The other way to set `DbType` for second parameter is `updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productPrice", _ProductPrice).OleDbType = OleDbType.Currency;`. There's no difference between them, since the goal is setting parameter type matching `productPrice` column data type.

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: I suggest you checking both input parameter values (`_ProductID` & `_ProductPrice`) and connection string after the code has modified with corrections above. Ensure values being sent to the method is not populated from the DB ones, instead coming from the form which sending them.

Comment: Figured it out, but thanks for your help.  arigato gozaimasu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Access doesn't care about the parameterized names, so much as the order they appear in.  So by changing the code to below, it works.

```
public int ChangeProduct(string _ProductID, double _ProductPrice)
    {
        int a = 0;
        string queryString = "UPDATE product SET productPrice = @productPrice WHERE productID = @productId";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {

            OleDbCommand updateProduct = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productPrice", _ProductPrice);
            updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", _ProductID);
            connection.Open();
            a = updateProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        } 
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: @LeiYang, he changed the order in adding the parameters to the OleDbCommand but I'm not sure why this should change anything.

Comment: I'm not sure why either, but it did work.  Apparently access looks at the position of the parameters and not the names.  So they have to be added in the order they appear in the query.